Every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is totally bounded.
I'm aware of similar statements having been proven in this forum, however not this exact one. I think the proof is really simple though I'd like some verification.
Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Then $\bar{A}$ is bounded and closed. As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it is compact. Thus, it is totally bounded. Since $A\subseteq\bar{A}$, A is also totally bounded.If the logic is sound, do you think that it demands further explanation? Maybe on the part "Since $A\subseteq\bar{A}$, A is also totally bounded" ? The context is undergrad Real Analysis final exams.

This can be proven more directly.
Because $A$ is bounded it is a subset of $[-M, M]$ for some real number $M > 0$.
Take any positive real number $\epsilon$, then we need to show that $A$ can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\epsilon$, these are intervals of length $2\epsilon$.
Take an integer $n > \frac{M}{\epsilon}$. Consider the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of intervals $((i-1)\epsilon, (i+1)\epsilon)$ for $i$ an integer ranging from $-n$ to $n$.
For any point $x\in [-M, M]$ the point $\epsilon x \in [-n, n]$. Let $\lfloor x\rfloor = j$ then $|j|\leq n$ and $\epsilon x \in (j-1, j+1)$.
This shows that the collection $\mathcal{B}$ covers $[-M, M]$ and so it also covers $A$.
You can most likely skip a few steps of this proof depending on the theory built up in your course up to this point.
For example you could take as given that $[-M, M]$ is absolutely bounded and that a subset of an absolutely bounded set is absolutely bounded. This immediately proves that $A$ is absolutely bounded.

Thanks a lot for the help
